# Materialize- A Dropdown inside a tab

Tags: html, frontend, materialize

I need a dropdown like [this](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) inside a tab like [this](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html), I want the dropdown as tab using Materialize. How can I do this?

Comment: Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown in nav-extended what you want is an open issue for more information you can see the following link - [github issues #3920](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3920)

Comment: Thanks! I tried a navbar work around as suggested in the link you've sent. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
  <nav class="nav-extended">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="top-nav">
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
               <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="drop-tab">
        <li>
            <!--<a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a>-->
        </li>
      </ul>
        <ul materialize="tabs" class="tabs tabs-transparent">

            <li class="tab space-tab"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test5">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test6">Disabled Tab</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a materialize="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-button"  data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div>something</div>
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content black white-text">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs {
     overflow-x: visible !important;
     overflow-y: initial !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.